# Enable/Disable editing view

Tags: docusignapi

I am building a website with Django (Python), and I want to use the DocuSign API to interact with PDF files.
I am using the [django-docusign module](https://github.com/peopledoc/django-docusign) to interact with the DocuSign API, and I studied the DocuSign REST API documentation in order to let my senders edit the PDFs (add the tabs), and send the documents to signers.

First of all, the workflow for my Django app is:
1. *user A* uploads a document and adds tabs using a web GUI (but he can't sign the document - the web GUI is provided by DocuSign using the `XXX/views/recipient` API route),
2. as soon as *user A* finished to review/edit the document, a new user (*user B*) fills the blanks and signs the document (but he can't edit it).
So, I don't want to let *user A* signs the document (but, *user A* can sign it later as *user B*), and I don't want to let *user B* modifies the document and the tabs.

Currently, the problem I have is: how can I restrict the usage of the web GUI (provided by `XXX/views/recipient` API route mainly) in order to let the *user B* fills the blanks and **not** edit the document?
I think I need to modify the default envelope of the Django module to add some options, right?

Also, using the Django module, I don't have any model about the Sender of the document - only the Signer. So, the Signer is the same than the Sender (if I understand clearly the rights of each model).
Do I need to create a new model for a Sender, overriding the `SignerFactory` class?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

`XXX/views/recipient` API is used to creating the embedded signing view for the embedded signers, it cannot be used for doing tagging on the document. If you want to allow UserA to do tagging or uploading a document on an envelope, then you need to use:

```
POST /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/views/sender
```

this will open the sender View and allows the UserA to do tagging, when userB is planning to sign then do not call above API, instead call below API to start the embedded signing for userB, with below API, userB will not be allowed to do any tagging or uploading work.

```
POST /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/views/recipient
```

You can learn all types of views which you can open for an envelope by checking [DocuSign Docs](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeViews/).